# Каким образом можно отбросить ненужные строки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

**Мой код:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('PS_2022.01.12_02.04.06.csv', index_col=None, sep=',', comment='#')
planet_ser = df.reindex(columns=['pl_name', 'hostname','discoverymethod', 'disc_year', 'sy_dist', 'st_age', 'rowupdate'])
planet_df = pd.DataFrame(planet_ser)
new_df = planet_df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

У меня есть датафрейм, которые предоставляет информацию об открытиях планет. Некоторые строки между собой сходятся (одна и та же планета) почти по всем параметрам, кроме **st_age** (возраст планеты), это связано со столбцом **rowupdate** (последняя, и как я понимаю, более точная информация). Как я могу убрать старую информацию о планете, ориентируясь по **rowupdate**?

Датафрейм можно взять здесь: https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/TblView/nph-tblView?app=ExoTbls&config=PS

[image: Картинка]

Я пытался весьма странным способом это всё провернуть:

1. Найти все уникальные значения планет (**pl_name**)
2. Объединить уже их с остальными столбцами

Но это привело к тому, что везде где не сходились данные - появлялись NaN

На выходе хочу получить ±4800 уникальных планет

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Хорошо, добавил ссылку на файл, спасибо! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

посмотрите, вы что-то такое хотели?:

(для простоты оставил только два столбца)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('PS_2022.01.12_08.47.14.csv', index_col=None, sep=',', comment='#', parse_dates=['rowupdate'])

new_df = df.groupby(['pl_name']).agg({'rowupdate':'max'}).reset_index()
new_df.head()
'''
    pl_name     rowupdate
0   11 Com b    2014-07-23
1   11 UMi b    2018-09-04
2   14 And b    2014-07-23
3   14 Her b    2021-09-20
4   16 Cyg B b  2021-09-20
'''
df.shape, new_df.shape
'''
((31827, 2), (4884, 2))
```

**UPD**

чтобы остались все колонки можно сделать примерно так:

(столбцы выбраны произвольно, только для демонстрации)

```
new_df = df.iloc[df.groupby(['pl_name']).apply(lambda x: x['rowupdate'].idxmax())]
new_df.head()
'''
       pl_name  hostname   sy_dist  sy_disterr1  sy_disterr2  rowupdate
1     11 Com b    11 Com   93.1846       1.9238      -1.9238 2014-07-23
3     11 UMi b    11 UMi  125.3210       1.9765      -1.9765 2018-09-04
5     14 And b    14 And   75.4392       0.7140      -0.7140 2014-07-23
7     14 Her b    14 Her   17.9323       0.0073      -0.0073 2021-09-20
18  16 Cyg B b  16 Cyg B   21.1397       0.0110      -0.0111 2021-09-20
'''
df.shape, new_df.shape
'''
((31827, 6), (4884, 6))
```

возможно есть более простые и эффективные способы решить эту задачу, надеюсь знатоки pandas поделятся решением.

Comment: Да, это то, что я хотел.
Благодарю Вас!

Comment: @НикитаАнуфриев, а почему в вопросе ни слова о том, что в результате вам нужно получить только два столбца??

Comment: Прошу прощения, да, мне нужно не два столбца, а 6, как на картинке выше, но код @SergFSM помог мне решить мою проблему)